# I need the top screw demensions for a GE Profile™ Series 1.7 Cu. Ft. Convection Over-the-Range Microwave Oven

Tags: microwave-oven

I managed to fit our new GE Profile™ Series 1.7 Cu. Ft. Convection Over-the-Range Microwave Oven PVM9179SFSS into the wall mount but the holes I drilled for the top screws are in the wrong place. I would like to know how many inches back from the front and side the top screw holes are so that I can try to screw new holes without taking the microwave back off as it is firmly in place.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Have you tried looking at the [manual](http://products.geappliances.com/appliance/gea-specs/PVM9179SFSS)?

Comment: The installation instructions for almost all over-the-counter units come with a drilling template that shows the exact locations and gives instructions about adjusting for different types of cabinets.

Comment: @DanielGriscom -- your link gets to a page with a pdf of the install template... I'd call that a worthy answer.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate yeah... but it gets kind of old formally stating the obvious...